# How to show the current configuration of iptables with ufw?

Tags: iptables, ufw

This is what I get when I try to see the current iptables configuration:

```
nes@sw-eng:~$ sudo ufw show
ERROR: Unsupported action 'show'
```

So, what else is there?

Comment: You could always just `iptables -nL`

Answer (score 4):

Ufw doesn't have a show command try

```
ufw status
```

or

```
ufw status numbered
```

Have a look at the [ufw](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/ufw.8.html) man page.

Comment: That isn't very revealing when the firewall is still off.
`nes@sw-eng:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive`

Comment: This is related to your question how ?

Comment: @NikoSchwarz Sure it is, it's telling you exactly what the firewall is doing; that's what you asked it.

Comment: I'd like to see the rules that would be active if I switched the firewall on.

Comment: That really is a different question to the one you asked, `ufw show raw` may be what you want then.

Comment: No, sorry, that is precisely what I asked.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo ufw status`

[The Ubuntu community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) has a page dedicated to UFW.